# react router not working for nested components(transitionTo is invalid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactive-programming

I have parent grandchild dependency in my code.The main element is App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {ExpenseApp} from './expense-app.js'
import {Switch, BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js'

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path='/' component={ExpenseApp}/>
                <Route path='/fullblog' component={FullBlog}/>
            </BrowserRouter>
            )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExpenseApp data={data}/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

The expenseapp.js has a button through which I want another page to get loaded

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom' ;
import $ from 'jquery' ;
//import data from '../data.json';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js';
import {Author} from './Author.js'


class ExpenseApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      data:this.props.data,
      list:[]
    }
  }
  render(){
    var data=this.state.data;
    var list=this.state.list;
    var len= Object.keys(data).length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
      //console.log(data[i]);
      list.push(<Author key={i} i={i} data={data[i]}/>);
    }
    return(
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
      )
  }
}

module.exports={
  ExpenseApp:ExpenseApp
}
```

the Author.js is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom' ;
import $ from 'jquery' ;
//import data from '../data.json';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js'


class Author extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      data:this.props.data,
      load:false,
      content:'',
      Author:'',
      Book:''
    }
    this.loadBlog=this.loadBlog.bind(this);
  }

  loadBlog(i){
    var that=this;
    var data=this.state.data[i];
    that.setState({
     // load:true,
      Content:this.props.data.Content,

    })
    that.context.Router.transitionTo(null,'/fullblog');
  }
  render(){
   if(this.state.load===false){    
      return(

        <div onClick={this.loadBlog} >
          <div>{this.props.data.Author}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Book}</div>
        </div>

        )
       }//else{
      //   return(<Link to="/fullblog"><FullBlog data={this.state.data}/></Link>)
      // }
  }
}

Author.contextTypes = {
  Router: function contextType() {
    return React.PropTypes.func.isRequired;
  }
};
module.exports={
  Author:Author
}
```

And then there is FullBlog.js

```
class FullBlog extends React.Component{
render(){
return(<div>Hello world</div>)
}
} 
module.exports={
  FullBlog:FullBlog
}
```

And the error that I am getting is [image: error]
But through this, I am not able to navigate to anything.I am using React-router for the first time and I dont know what the issue is. Thanks

Comment: If you reorder the path's to where `/fullblog` is first, does that allow you to navigate through?

Comment: no it doesn't even then. @enjoylife

Comment: Oh you should probably export your components as default as it looks like your imports might be causing the issue, Try debuging or using console.log on the component your passing to the Route as it looks like its not actually a component.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain more! As far as I understand FullBlog is already a component then why is this issue coming? @enjoylife

Comment: even after exporting as default, I get the same error @enjoylife

Comment: Well the error states you should check the `Author` component, as react tries to render `{this.props.Author}`, but it can't because its something unexpected.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check

Comment: could you take a moment and format your code properly please?

Comment: please check again @azium

Answer (score 0):

You should use react routers [`withRouter()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher order function. You pass in your component and `withRouter` adds a `router` object to your component props.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

export default withRouter(Author)
```

Then instead of calling `Router.transitionTo` (I'm not sure thats a thing) you would call `this.props.router.history.push('/somepath')`